# Error when running ls "exa: error while loading shared libraries: libgit2.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: ls, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro Linux and upon running the `ls` command or any variation of it with flags I get the error:

```
exa: error while loading shared libraries: libgit2.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I haven't been able to find any one with this issue online, or any solutions. Let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks.

-Linkio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know Manjoro Linux. I guess a good start is to type `/bin/ls`. If it works, this seems that `ls` is aliases to `exa -l`. The `type ls` command shows you if `ls` is aliased. Aliased are typically defined in `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: I ran `/bin/ls` and that gave a normal output, so I went into the `.bashrc` file and changed the alias to `alias ls=-'/bin/ls'`, but even after that when I run the `ls` command I still get the same error.

Comment: `alias ls=-'/bin/ls'` or `alias ls='/bin/ls'` (The minus char removed). 

Note that the normal way to unalias is `unalias ls`.